# Qt3D uniform int array

Tags: arrays, glsl, shader, qt3d, uniform

i am trying to implement a shader with a uniform int array in Qt3D (C++, not qml):

The GLSL uniform is defined as follows:

```
uniform int data[4];
```

This uniform will be updated very often (thousands of times per frame). I used QParameter for single value uniforms. The documentation states, that the name of the uniform should be "data[0]" for the registration of the QParameter. What is any / the fastest way to set the uniform array? The data to be set is stored in a  uint32_t[4] array.

I would appreciate any help very much!

Best regards

Edit:

Thank you for the hint Rabbit76, 
I changed to definition to ivec4. 
Unfortunatelly, I still don't know how to pass the data. 
I tried something similar to this

```
char data[4];
//*** set data to wanted values ***//
QByteArray dataArray;
dataArray.setRawData(data,4);
QParameter("data",dataArray, this); //*** this is a pointer to a subclassed QMaterial
```

but the data is not set and I get a qWarning like e.g.

```
Unknown uniform type or value: QVariant(QByteArray, "\x80\xA7\x1D\x93;\x01\x00\x00\xDF\x88\x11\xA7\xFD\x7F\x00\x00") Please check your QParameters
```

for the real data.

I tried to search the documentation and source code of Qt3D, but could not find the valid type of data to pass to the QVariant argument.
Is there any possibility to directly set the uniform variable and bypass the QVariant in QT3D?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array is 4, then I recommend to use `ivec4` instead of `int[4]`.

```c
uniform ivec4 data;
```

The elements of `data` can be access with array syntax (e.g. `data[0]`).